# Wordpress additional fields radio buttons

Tags: wordpress

I have created a custom post type for recipients and a additional field for recipient gender. I have created a form on front end to add recipient with all required fields. But when i am submitting the form a new post added in recipients with all fields excepting the gender field. Gender field are radio buttons. Here is the code of additional field:

```
array (
    'key' => 'field_5426684ccbad6',
    'label' => 'Gender',
    'name' => 'gender',
    'type' => 'radio',
    'required' => 1,
    'choices' => array (
        'male' => 'Male',
        'female' => 'Female',
    ),
    'other_choice' => 0,
    'save_other_choice' => 0,
    'default_value' => '',
    'layout' => 'horizontal',
),
```

Please tell me how to update the gender field from front end?

Comment: This code you are using is  front end?

Comment: No, this code is used to create custom field for gender and i am using add_post_meta($post_id, 'field_5426684ccbad6', 'male'); to add the value.

Comment: Use update_post_meta instead of add_post_meta

Comment: and on backend please check the output of this field like <?php echo get_post_meta($post_id, 'field_5426684ccbad6', true); ?>

Comment: Thanks for quick help Ravi, update post meta works properly, i don't know the reason, but it's working properly.

Comment: You are welcome mate. Can you vote my answer please

Answer (score 0):

Use `update_post_meta` instead of `add_post_meta`